# Wicket wicket:head meta on all extended pages

Tags: java, wicket

Hi i have problem with wicket:head. i define in HTML this head.

```html
<wicket:head>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250"/>
</wicket:head>
```

and i want have this head on all pages. When i start my web app and inspect content of page i see this head on first/initial page but no on another pages. Please, have you som idea? thanks for all ideas

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating something like BasePage.java and BasePage.html, and then have all the pages extend BasePage.java and, have associated markup pages as html being wicket:extend using header,  body,  footer template.  For more information,  I would suggest you to go through wicket template and XHTML tags chapter of you have not already.